# How to set Sharepoint column value from Azure Active Directory AAD

Tags: list, sharepoint, drop-down-menu, azure-active-directory, set

So I am creating a list of Sharepoint for the first time. I want the column dropdown value instead of adding all users name manual, I want the list to get them from Azure Active directory.

**Sharepoint:**

[image]

**Azure Active Directory:**

[image]

Is there any direct way to accomplished or it requires a connector between them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any direct way but a solution could be to write a PowerShell script or some sort of console app that executes on a schedule and consumes graph API endpoint to get users information and populates a particular (custom) list in your SharePoint site. Then you can create a lookup column in desired list that looks up user information in your users list.